# Does the -depth option of find imply depth-first tree traversal?

Tags: find

As I understand it the `-depth` option of the `find` command causes the specified actions to take place on the way out of a directory (and maybe I understand it wrong) during a depth-first traversal of a tree structure.

Without the `-depth` option specified, does it normally make an action occur before the depth-first traversal is complete, or does it do a breadth-first traversal of the directories and run the action first normally?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`find` uses a depth-first strategy (as opposed to breadth-first), whether `-depth` is specified or not. `-depth` only guarantees that sub-directories are processed before their parents.

A quick example:

```
mkdir -p a/{1,2,3} b c
find .
```

produces

```
.
./a
./a/2
./a/1
./a/3
./b
./c
```

whereas

```
find . -depth
```

produces

```
./a/2
./a/1
./a/3
./a
./b
./c
.
```

If you want breadth-first search, you can use [`bfs`](https://github.com/tavianator/bfs) which is a breadth-first implementation of `find`.

Comment: Also I just noticed that using -depth clobbers the use of e.g. -name .git -prune to skip processing of the git folder... I wonder if there is another way to tell find to exclude some subfolders, which works despite -depth ?

Comment: @Razzle `-prune` *can’t* work with `-depth` because the latter causes subdirectories to be processed first — so by the time `-prune` comes into play, the subdirectories and files which would be pruned have already been processed. The alternatives depend on your exact use-case, for example `find . -depth \( -path './.git*' -prune \) -o -print` skips `.git` and its contents. Perhaps you could [ask a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with the details of what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Seems to me you just showed me a way to use -depth while omitting .git and its subfolders - Bravo! (If it works when I test it :D ). But didn't you also just contradict yourself by demonstrating that prune _can_ work with depth? (You just need to add the pruning clause in the brackets?) -Thanks!

Comment: You lose the major feature of `-prune` which is to reduce the amount of processing required. The command above is effectively equivalent to `find . -depth ! -path './.git*'`.

Comment: Sadly `find . -depth \( -path './.git*' -prune \) -o -print` did not skip .git and its contents, when I just now tried it.

HOWEVER the suggested equivalent command (tweaked a bit here: only dirs) `find . -depth ! -path './.git*' -type d` DID give me the folder tree (depth first listing) while excluding the .git contents.  BRAVO and thanks!  I have never really got to grips with negations in find paths. Must give them a closer look...

Comment: @Razzle that’s odd, it works for me... You mean that `find . -depth \( -path './.git*' -prune \) -o -print | grep ./.git` produces output?

Comment: Yes, huge number of files under .git/hooks and .git/logs etc. comes out from the pruning version (Im using MinGW ie a git bash shell to test this out btw)

Comment: OK, I’m not sure why it would fail on MinGW, but I don’t have a Windows environment to figure it out.

Comment: Is the man page for GNU `find` wrong/misleading?

"The `-depth` option for example makes `find` traverse the file system in a depth-first order."

Comment: @KarelVlk yes, it is misleading...